# Error migrating Worklight 5.0.6 project to 6.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I am receiving an error trying to upgrade my Worklight project from v5.0.6 to v6.1.  I have done all of the pre-migration steps, including removing Tealeaf libraries from the project and adding the new analytics settings to the initOptions.js file.

During the migration, it fails in the step where it is trying to add Worklight Analytics properties to the Worklight properties file.  I am getting the following error:

```
Migrator class com.worklight.upgrader.upgraders.ios.AppAddAnalyticsIPhonePlistXMLUpgrader has failed 
Migrating the bcbst_mma_app_wl project from version 5.0.6 to version 6.1.0.0 has failed because Failed reading bcbstmmaappwlMmaIphone-Info.plist
```

I am not sure what is causing the issue.  I thought it may be file permissions since I am using a copy of the actual 5.0.6 project, but the permissions look fine.  I have been able to "successfully" migrate the project before by removing that plist file before the upgrade, but the upgrade complained that the file was missing, and it never really worked correctly.

I am using the Consumer edition of Worklight, in case that makes any difference.

**EDIT** I got the migration to work. I did a chmod 777 on all of the files in the directory and it worked. Not an ideal solution, but it worked. Thanks to @mikerott for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Did you try with 6.1.0.1 instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a Mac?  Often importing projects with the "copy into workspace" checkbox checked will result in files being placed with the Mac "locked" file permission bit set.

Please find the `bcbstmmaappwlMmaIphone-Info.plist` file in Finder, right-click -> Get Info.  See if the "Locked" checkbox is checked.  If so, uncheck it and see if you encounter the same problem.

[image]

You may have to do this with multiple files.

Comment: The files were not showing as locked. However, I took your idea of locked files and did a chmod 777 on the directory and the migration worked. Thanks @mikerott